# VBA Flatten Hierarchical array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical array that I want to flatten so that it will be easier to iterate through.
What's the best way to flatten a hierarchical array in VBA?

**Visual** of hierarchical array:

```
s
    p
    t
        d
        n
x
```

**Visual** of flattened array

```
s
p
t
d
n
x
```

**Implemented** hierarchical array:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    Dim v() As Variant
    v = Array("s", Array("p", "t", Array("d", "n")), "x")

    MsgBox printHier(v)
End Sub

Function printHier(v, Optional layer As Integer = 0) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    indent = layer * 4
    Do While indent > 0
        output = output & " "
        indent = indent - 1
    Loop
    printHier = output & CStr(v)

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    For Each subv In v
        If printHier = vbNullString Then
            printHier = printHier(subv, layer + 1)
        Else
            printHier = printHier & vbNewLine & printHier(subv, layer + 1)
        End If
    Next subv
End Function
```

Comment: Why not write each member to a second array `v_flat` that has only one level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "best" way, but here's one approach:

```
Sub test()
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim arrout()

    v = Array("s", Array("p", "t", Array("d", "n", Array("x", "y"))), "x")
    ReDim arrout(0 To 0)
    Flatten v, arrout

    Debug.Print Join(arrout, ",")

End Sub

Sub Flatten(arrIn, arrout)
Dim v, a, ub
    For Each v In arrIn
        If TypeName(v) Like "*()" Then
            Flatten v, arrout
        Else
            If IsEmpty(arrout(0)) Then
                arrout(0) = v
            Else
                ub = UBound(arrout)
                ReDim Preserve arrout(0 To ub + 1)
                arrout(ub + 1) = v
            End If
        End If
    Next v
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I'm unfamiliar with the Like operator, what does "*()" actually mean in this case?

Comment: @Alter - The `*` in `Like "*()"` is a wildcard which can represent zero or more characters: basically it's looking for a string ending in "()".

Comment: Is there a reason you use a sub with an argument for output, rather than using a function with a return value?

Comment: Does testing the `TypeName` for `()` work better than the `IsArray` function?